# Expected Value multiple dice throws

Tags: probability, puzzle

I am solving this particular question :

A very innocent monkey throws a fair die. The monkey will eat as many bananas as are shown on the die, from 1 to 5. But if the die shows '6', the monkey will eat 5 bananas and throw the die again. This may continue indefinitely. What is the expected number of bananas the monkey will eat?

The correct answer is 4, but I am getting 3. Cannot figure out what is wrong with this approach:

$ E[x] = \Sigma P[x]x $

$E[x] = (1/6)(1+2+3+4+5) + 1/6(5 + 1/6(1 +2 +3+4+5)....) $

$E[x] = 5/2 + 1/6(E[x] + 5) $

Solving this I get 3 but the correct answer as shown in the image is 4

[image]

Comment: Solving what you wrote on the third line, I get $4$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where your equations come from.

Two things can happen on the first toss.  Either he throws $≤5$ and the game ends (after some bananas are consumed), or he throws a $6$ and the game restarts (again, after some eating).

Thus $$E=\frac 16\times 15+\frac 16\times (5+E)\implies E=4$$

Comment: He has the same equation. He just did an error when solving it apparently.

Comment: @nicomezi  Yes, that makes sense.  It's the second equation that puzzles me...though perhaps it  is just intended to rewrite the third.

Comment: I agree this is not a very rigourous way to derive the equation.

Comment: I did an error while solving, this is embarrassing.

Comment: If I can comfort you, I also did an error when I tried to solve it (Friday afternoons ...).

Comment: @DhruvMahajan  Oh, no need to apologize for that.  We all make mistakes of that form.

Comment: @DhruvMahajan - IMHO it's much preferable to have an algebraic error, than an error in understanding the actual theory of probabilities.  Won't comfort you in the case of an exam, but in a platonic sense...